# Complex Joins in Pandas

Tags: sql, join, merge, pandas

How can you write this in Pandas? Is it just better to use SQL?

I have tried "where", "isin", "join", "merge", and I am not able to replicate this in Pandas.

***Problem:***
I basically have two columns (x & y) with values one through 10. I then want to do a self join with a specific criteria shown below.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t1','u') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
DROP TABLE #t1
END

    CREATE TABLE #t1
    (
        x int,
        y int
    )

INSERT #t1
select distinct number as x, number as y from Master..spt_values
where number between 1 and 10
order by number

select a.x as a_x,
        a.y as a_y,
        b.x as b_x,
        b.y as b_y
from #t1 as a
join #t1 as b on (a.x <= b.x and a.x > b.x-4)
order by a.x,a.y
```

Any suggestions?

***Here are the results of the query for those who don't have SQL:***

a_x a_y b_x b_y
1   1   1   1
1   1   2   2
1   1   3   3
1   1   4   4
2   2   2   2
2   2   3   3
2   2   4   4
2   2   5   5
3   3   3   3
3   3   4   4
3   3   5   5
3   3   6   6
4   4   4   4
4   4   5   5
4   4   6   6
4   4   7   7
5   5   5   5
5   5   6   6
5   5   7   7
5   5   8   8
6   6   6   6
6   6   7   7
6   6   8   8
6   6   9   9
7   7   7   7
7   7   8   8
7   7   9   9
7   7   10  10
8   8   8   8
8   8   9   9
8   8   10  10
9   9   9   9
9   9   10  10
10  10  10  10

***Here is the dataframe***

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':range(1,11),
                   'y':range(1,11)})
```

Comment: can you be more clear about what the initial dataframe would look like? namely, are the values randomly assigned? are they sorted? do they repeat?

Comment: when `x` and `y` are the same and (aliased) tables `a` and `b` are the same, i don't understand how `a.x <= b.x and a.x > b.x-4` would ever by `False`

Comment: If we pick a random x value like 9......then....9 < 10 and 9 > 10-4....this will be TRUE

Comment: can you post a fiddle with your DB schema? (http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':range(1,11),
                   'y':range(1,11)})
df2 = pd.merge(df, df, on=np.ones(df.shape[0]), suffixes=("_a", "_b")).drop("key_0", axis=1)
print df2.query("x_a <= x_b & x_a > x_b - 4").reset_index(drop=True)
```

the output is:

```
    x_a  y_a  x_b  y_b
0     1    1    1    1
1     1    1    2    2
2     1    1    3    3
3     1    1    4    4
4     2    2    2    2
5     2    2    3    3
6     2    2    4    4
7     2    2    5    5
8     3    3    3    3
9     3    3    4    4
10    3    3    5    5
11    3    3    6    6
12    4    4    4    4
13    4    4    5    5
14    4    4    6    6
15    4    4    7    7
16    5    5    5    5
17    5    5    6    6
18    5    5    7    7
19    5    5    8    8
20    6    6    6    6
21    6    6    7    7
22    6    6    8    8
23    6    6    9    9
24    7    7    7    7
25    7    7    8    8
26    7    7    9    9
27    7    7   10   10
28    8    8    8    8
29    8    8    9    9
30    8    8   10   10
31    9    9    9    9
32    9    9   10   10
33   10   10   10   10
```

Comment: Do you know if there is an alternate way aside from the cartesian method? I am looking for something that would work on large data sets.

Comment: I can't think any simple method that can do the join less than O(N**2). Are you sure the SQL don't check every pair values? Maybe sort the `x` column, and for every value `v` in `x`, binary search `v+4`, but it's a little complicated.