# Python Join two dataframes on columns meeting a condition

Tags: python, join, pandas

Say I have two dataframes A and B, each containing two columns called x and y.
I want to join these two dataframes but not on rows on which the x and y columns are equal across the two dataframes, but on rows where A's x columns is a substring of B's x column and same for y.
For example

```
if A[x][1]='mpla' and B[x][1]='mplampla'
```

I would want that to be captured.

On sql it would be something like:

```
select *
from A
join B
on A.x<=B.x and A.y<=B.y.
```

Can something like this be done on python?

Comment: The SQL you gave does not implement what you described.  Which one do you want: substring matching, or lexicographical comparison?

Comment: Oh I know, it was just an example. On this specific occasion I need substring matching. But I ideally I would like to learn if there is way to implement it for other relationships too (for example, if I had numbers etc...)

Comment: Here is a similar question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22723286/complex-joins-in-pandas

Answer (score 0):

You can match a single string at a time against all the strings in one column, like this:

```
import numpy.core.defchararray as ca

ca.find(B.x.values.astype(str), 'mpla') >= 0
```

The problem with that is you'll have to loop over all elements of `A`.  But if you can afford that, it should work.

See also: [pandas + dataframe - select by partial string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350770/pandas-dataframe-select-by-partial-string)

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a shot, but they are both very large files that's why I'm looking for a more efficient way.

Comment: If you can't find anything in the standard packages, you should consider writing your own C extension.  Then you could implement whatever efficient algorithm you can think of.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like

```
B.x.where(B.x.str.contains(A.x), B.index,         axis=index) #this would give you the ones that don't match 


B.x.where(B.x.str.match(A.x, as_indexer=True), B.index, axis=index) #this would also give you the one's that don't match.  You could see if you can use the "^" operator used for regex to get the ones that match.
```

You could also maybe try

```
np.where(B.x.str.contains(A.x), B.index, np.nan)
```

also you can try:

```
matchingmask = B[B.x.str.contains(A.x)]

matchingframe = B.ix[matchingmask.index] #or 

matchingcolumn = B.ix[matchingmask.index].x #or

matchingindex = B.ix[matchingmask.index].index
```

All of these assume you have the same index on both frames (I think)

You want to look at the string methods: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#text-string-methods

you want to read up on regex and pandas where method: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#the-where-method-and-masking